# amazon EC2 network connectivity setup

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have two VM's on an amazon VPC (same region/availability zone) - they have the same VPC and subnet ID.  Should I be able to use the private IP address from one VM to another (as is) or do I need to take additional steps to make that happen (assuming that the security group/ufw is not blocking traffic for the ports I am using for connectivity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your security groups allow the traffic (and by default they do), yes communication between two instances on the same subnet is possible.

Answer (score 1):

VPC is just normal vlan, so yes, all instances within same VPC can communicate with private IPs without any problem (ofc if security groups and firewalls on instances allows it), it is even better, because you don't want to have public IP assigned to ie. database servers.